# Won't boot after upgrade 18.04, encrypted swap

Tags: boot, encryption, swap, 18.04

Forgive me, I'm typing from my phone due to inoperable OS.

The OS won't finish booting and I can't get to the desktop. I can however drop to a console.

On boot, no matter the contents of fstab, it prompts me for the key to the encrypted swap partition (which was previously normal) and then drops out of the GUI screen and to some system screen checklist and then eventually stops loading.

I had previously had an encrypted swap (cryptfs or some such, the one that was supposed to allow hibernation) on 17.10. I think this is the problem.

Steps I've taken:
1. I check fstab and the swap partition was commented out, so I uncommented it. Didn't work. Went back and commented it out again. 
2. I edited etc/initrmfs tools/conf.d/resume to comment out the partition in there 
3. Exec update-initramfs -uk all to update initramfs

No dice. Still can't get to a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the two steps I mentioned in my question, here's what I did to solve the problem:

1. removed/commented out the line in `/etc/crypttab` that corresponded to the swap partition -- `cryptswap1 /dev/sda5 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256`
2. removed/commented out all swap related lines in `/etc/fstab`, including the line `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`

Note: you probably won't have any swap after this, unless your installation is successfully using a swapfile as well.